# What does this apache rewrite means?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    (.*)\?mem=stats$
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$           http://X.X.X.X/$1?%1 [P,L]
```

If the request is `/asdf?mem=stats`, will it rewrite to `/asdf?mem=stats?asdf` ?

since `$1` is `asdf?mem=stats` and `%1` is `asdf` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable contains the query string without the leading `?` (or anything before it), so `%1` will never contain part of the request before query string.

If you enable mod_rewrite logging by adding `LogLevel rewrite:trace6` to your VirtualHost configuration, you will see this for your RewriteCond and `/asdf?mem=stats` request:

```
... RewriteCond: input='mem=stats' pattern='(.*)\\?mem=stats$' => not-matched
```

Also, in your `RewriteRule`, pattern will be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string. Therefore `$1`will, even on wildcard match, not contain the query string part of the request. You can see that in log as:

```
... applying pattern '^/(.*)$' to uri '/asdf'
```